# loop through and perform operations with values of a vector

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have this vector:

```
a = c(6722, 487,  5919, 179, 7305, 336, 10015, 615,  8651, 253, 679, 75,  8652, 118, 11436, 229)
```

and I need to create a new vector with the ratio of pairs of values like this:

```
ratio = c(a[2]/a[1], a[4]/a[3], a[6]/a[5]... etc)
```

so the output should look like this:

```
ratio    num[1:8] 0.0724 0.03024 0.04599 etc   (edited)
```

I tried the following code:

```
ratio = c()
  for (i in length(a)){
    ratio[i] = a[2*i]/a[2*i-1]
  }
```

and got this:

```
Error in a[0+2i] : invalid subscript type 'complex'
```

after I figured out that R thought I meant i = sqrt(-1), I tried this:

```
ratio = c()
 for (i in length(a)){
    ratio[i] = a[i+i]/a[i+i-1]
  }
```

which produced:

```
> ratio
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

then I tried with lapply:

```
lapply(a, function(x)
    a[x+i]/a[x+i-1])
```

which gave me a 16-element list full of NAs.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `a[2i]/a[2i-1]` - you need to multiply as `2*i`, not `2i`

Comment: Your example output is wrong. `a[2]/a[1]` is not 7.25

Comment: @Frank - yes, thanks for the heads-up. copied the percentages instead of the ratios. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a `for` loop here, try just (not sure if you need `* 100L` at the end as your description doesn't match desired output)

```
a[c(FALSE, TRUE)]/ a[c(TRUE, FALSE)] * 100L
## [1]  7.244868  3.024159  4.599589  6.140789  2.924517 11.045655  1.363847  2.002448
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks David. If you have the time/inclination, would you mind explaining how this solution works? much appreciated!

Comment: This is a simple recycling mechanism that is builtin in R. If a longer vector is being subseted by a shorter one (or `cbind`ed to a shorter one, for instance), the shorter vector is being recycled, so you will get `FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE`, etc. until it will reach the size of the longer vector.